# Locally run the Vault UI for a remote Vault server

Tags: hashicorp-vault

Is there any way to run the Vault web UI locally but manage an actual Vault server located elsewhere?
I've parsed their docs - the seem to indicate that setting some environment variables before starting `vault server -address=****` should do the trick, but it doesn't seem to work.

I can't tell if what I'm doing should be possible or not.

I'm actually leaning towards not possible.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, its possible. 
You need to access the UI using the IP address of the server, say for example if the IP address is ****, then you access the UI by going to the browser and typing http://****/ui.
If you are using TLS connection, then you have to create a certificate with the IP sans as the IP address of the server and type https://****/ui. 
Btw, UI has to be enabled in the config file of the server

Answer (score 0):

- Into */etc/vault.d/vault.hcl*, On the section HTTP (or HTTPS), put the public **address** of your server.
- Set the public ip of your server as an environment variable with the key `VAULT_ADDR`.

**Note**:

- You may also need to uncomment `disable_mlock=true` (or even comment the section related to HTTPS)
- You may need to run source X (X : path to your env. vars. file)